# pip install windows-curser displaying error

Tags: python, python-curses

I wanted to install `curses` to do a project on menu making system using Python. When I tried to import curses in jupyter, I received an error telling me there is no package such as curser... So I tried to install the curser using pip install.
This is what I typed:

```
pip install windows-curser
```

And I received an error written like this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curser (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for windows-curser
```

This is the full error message I get:

[image]

Comment: `curses` != `curser`, this seems to be a simply typo. As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting confused between `windows-curses` and `windows-curser`? I don't know, but "curses" is a common library, and "curser" I haven't heard of.

Edit: After some searching, yes, `windows-curses` is a python package, but `windows-curser` doesn't appear anywhere. I think this was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install `curses` because it is part of the standard library. But not on Windows. The documentation says

The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. A ported version called UniCurses is available. You could also try the Console module written by Fredrik Lundh, which doesn’t use the same API as curses but provides cursor-addressable text output and full support for mouse and keyboard input.